# OWIN Middleware kills WebApi.Helppage

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a ASP.NET WebApi Project that uses Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebApi.HelpPage nuget project (version 5.2.2)
When adding
app.UseWebApi(config);
to the startup.cs when I try and access a method on the help I get the following error:

> This method or property is not supported after
>   HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked 
>   [Stack Trace]: 
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureFiles() +3274833
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files() +12
>   System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Files() +28...

removing the line and the problem goes away.

I am using VS2013 targeting .Net Version 4.5.1 and debugging using IIS Express. All Nuget Packages are running the latest as of today

Comment: Nope - just commented out that line.